# What db structure should I use for a form with LOTS of checkboxes that each user must fill out?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, webforms

Thank you all in advance for helping someone new to web development.

I am a little overwhelmed by a very large and complicated form for my first project. Several sections of the form present the user with large groups of check-boxes, asking the user to select which health conditions apply to them. Some of the health conditions appear in more than one such section of the form.

Should I structure this as a many-to-many relationship with a table of conditions and an intersection table? Or is this one user to many, as each user only has to fill out each section once? If it's the latter, I could create only one table with userID and conditionName, but some conditionName's would appear several times

If you think it should be a many-to-many relationship, what is the best way of inputting at least 100 health conditions into a health condition table (conditionID, conditionName)?

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea with the intersection table idea:

```
User Table
----------
userId (PK, AI)
...

Condition Table
----------
conditionId (PK, AI)
name
...

UserCondition
----------
userConditionId (PK, AI)
userId (FK)
conditionId (FK)
```

The UserCondition table has it's own auto-incrementing Primary Key.  This allows you to add the same condition to the same user multiple times if desired.

Comment: Adding rows to your db should be fairly straight-forward, consult the docs for your preferred DBMS.  If that doesn't work for you for whatever reason, whip up a web form to insert into the table.  It will be good practice for you.

Comment: As I asked above, how do I then store whatever conditions the user selects? 

@Matt: I know how to add rows using phpMyAdmin, it's just a pain in the butt to do it for 100 entries. I was wondering if there is a faster way . . .